# vue.js prevent line breaks when using v-on keydown

Tags: vue.js

I have a textarea that is bound to a v-model.
Upon pressing enter, I submit the textarea value and clear the model value.
The problem is that after that submit function runs, I'm left with the textarea having a line break as it registers the final enter key.

I've tried binding onkeyup | key 'enter' to return false to no avail.

```
<textarea class="chat-input" v-model="message" 
    v-on="keydown: onSubmit(chat, $event) | key 'enter'">
</textarea>
```

is there a way I can prevent the line break from occurring after my submit function runs?

Comment: Have you tried calling `event.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
event.preventDefault()
```

was the soultion.